# How to add a name to the columns of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Sample underlined in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUtxs.png)

This is what I'm trying to achieve. Is there something similar to adding a name to the index or is this not possible?

Comment: `df.columns.names = ['AIRLINE']` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This looks like a crosstab check out pd.Crosstab

Answer (score 1):

I am considering a few rows and columns of your dataframe.

Input:

```
df
               AA   AS
DAY_OF_WEEK     
  1           617   2129
  2           9793  9723
  3           4814  4814
```

Just, do this

```
df.columns.name = 'AIRLINE'
df
```

Output:

```
AIRLINE         AA    AS
DAY_OF_WEEK     
1              617   2129
2              9793  9723
3              4814  4814
```